# Is "overcome with" suitable to describe possible actions?

Tags: word-usage

I stumbled upon a usage of a "overcome with" in a programming [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29#typedef) (the first bullet right above the "See also" title) on Wikipedia and I am not sure if it is correct:
"They pollute the main namespace (see below), however this is easily overcome with prefixing a library name to the type name."

Now, this article is about the C programming language structs and the meaning of this sentence is simple: use 'library_type_t' instead of 'type_t' in certain cases. I would rephrase the above sentence as "... however, one could easily overcome this by prefixing a type name with a library name".

My question is whether the original usage was correct. My guess is that it was not since "overcome with" [is used to describe an emotional state](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Phrasal_Verbs/O/overcome_with_2077.htm) and not possible actions to solve a problem.

Comment: My instinct would be use "*overcome **by***" where that WP uses "*overcome with*", and to reserve "*overcome with*" for cases of someone being overwhelmed (by an emotion, eg). But it's also possible the original phrasing was an elision or deletion: "[this problem] can be overcome *with [the help of namespaces..]*".

Comment: It's not a phrasal verb -- simply the preposition "with" used for an instrument.

Comment: @GregLee good to know. I am going to edit the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They pollute the main namespace (see below), however this is easily overcome with prefixing a library name to the type name.

Replace `overcome with` with `corrected by` and it reads the same to me.

Overcome can mean an emotional state.  It can also mean success in the face of adversity.

> Overcome
>   verb
>
> succeed in dealing with (a problem or difficulty).
>
> "she worked hard to overcome her paralyzing shyness"
>   synonyms:   get the better of, prevail over, control, get/bring under control, master, conquer, defeat, beat; More
>
> defeat (an opponent); prevail.
>   "without firing a shot they overcame the guards"
>   synonyms:   defeat, beat, conquer, trounce, thrash, rout, vanquish, overwhelm, overpower, get the better of, triumph over, prevail over, win over/against, outdo, outclass, worst, crush; More
>
> (of an emotion) overpower or overwhelm.
>   "she was obviously overcome with excitement"
>   synonyms:   overwhelmed, emotional, moved, affected, speechless
>   "I was overcome"
>
> [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=overcome&oq=overcome&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

We shall overcome!

Comment: So the original is definitely incorrect, right?

Comment: No, as I said, it reads the same.  `I shall overcome with guile and courage` doesn't mean I'm getting emotional.  It means I'm gonna win.  Just because you can think of a better way to word it doesn't mean it's incorrect.